# How to get mean of every rowvalue in Dataframes efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median, memory-efficient

I have 5 dataframes which are build like that

```
                               A           B            C
2018-04-19 04:00:00     4.767408    4.767408     4.767408
2018-04-19 05:00:00     1.430304    3.683601     1.301930
2018-04-19 06:00:00     3.651601    0.207151     1.601330
2018-04-19 07:00:00     1.937919    1.301930     1.301930
2018-04-19 08:00:00     3.078898    3.751601     0.217151
   
2018-07-20 21:00:00     0.088575    1.301930     1.201930
2018-07-20 22:00:00     0.207151    0.038575     0.086775
2018-07-20 23:00:00     0.224044    0.217151     0.267151
2018-07-23 00:00:00     1.301930    0.988575     0.088573
2018-07-23 01:00:00    17.326162    1.301930     1.301930
```

The column names are dynamic (they always have the same name among the 5 dataframes, but sometimes in my programm they all are not called A,B,C but for example Car, Hamburger, Samurai_Sword).

How can i get One Dataframe where each value is a) the mean and b) the median of the same positional value from this DataFrame and the other DataFrames efficiently?

(indices are the same amoung all dfs)

Comment: `df.mean(axis=1)` ? or `df.select_dtypes('numeric').mean(axis=1)`

Comment: So, you want to create another two columns: `mean`, `median` to represent the **mean** and **median** of the rows... right?

Comment: @Anwarvic nope I want to create a new dataframe, in which every iloc is the mean of the exact same ilocs in the other 5 dataframes. (after that the same again but with median)

Comment: @Benoid any luck? Does my answer below help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple technique to get the mean and median of the **rows** of the dataframe using `pd.Series.describe()`:

`df.apply(pd.Series.describe, axis=1)[['mean','50%']]`

In order to do this, you need to merge the dataframes into one though. You can do this simply enough using `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,...], axis=1)`

At first I thought you just wanted the mean and median of the **columns**. If you want that, it's also simple using describe():

`df.describe().loc[['mean','50%']]`